# Flutter Driver Logs to a file

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I want to write Flutter driver logs to a file.
I tried   logging: ^0.11.4

```
Logger.root.onRecord.listen((record) {
  print('${record.level.name}: ${record.time}: ${record.message}');
});
```

But still, I can't listen to log on Flutter driver.
Is there any way to log or report the flutter driver data in a file?

Answer (score 1):

The most simple way to solve this is by writing the output to a file when you are starting the test driver;

flutter drive --driver=driver.dart --target=tests.dart > output.log